# Wireframe of a Hexahedron using Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d

Are there options in `Graphics3D` that would allow me to set the face color of a `Hexahedron` to `None` or make the faces transparent?

I did try `FaceForm`. But this may not work with `Graphics3D` primitives (or I am using it incorrectly).

I have the following code:

```
hexCoordinates = {{-12.5, -10,-6},{-12.5,10,6},{12.5,10,6},12.5,-10,6},{-6.5,-4,0}, {-6.5,4,0},{6.5,4,0},{6.5,-4,0}};

hexShape := Hexahedron[hexCoordinates];

Graphics3D[hexShape, Axes->True, FaceGrids->All, ImageSize->Full, Lighting->{{"Ambient",None}}]
```

Comment: Quit the kernel and run the code from this question. Then fix the code and update the question. Also, what did you try with FaceForm? It seems to work: `Graphics3D[{FaceForm@None, Hexahedron[]}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I tried FaceForm[] in the options list but received an error: "An improperly formatted option was encountered while reading a Graphics".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I gues the solution is `FaceForm[]`.

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Ball[{1, 1, 1}/2, 1/5]},
  {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Hexahedron[]}
  },
  FaceGrids -> All,
  Axes -> True,
  Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: boxWithFaceGrids]

Comment: This works if you don't need FaceGrids->All.  It looks like FaceForm[] causes FaceGrids and Axes to be ignored.  I am wondering if there is a way to have FaceForms[] with Axes->True and FaceGrids->All.

Comment: @DougKimzey I don't get interference between the `FaceGrids` and `FaceForm` directives: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cdv0.png

Comment: @DougKimzey are you sure you are following syntax from documentation? E.g. how did you end up with FaceForm in options in the first place. Now, what is the code you are descirbing above?

Comment: If I use:  Graphics3D[hexShape, FaceForm[], Axes->True, FaceGrids->All], the axes and grids appear but the hexahedron is solid.  An error message appears: "An improperly formatted option was encountered..."  If I use Graphics3D[{{hexShape, FaceForm[], Axes->True, FaceGrids->All}}] FaceForm, Axes and FaceGrids are ignored.

Comment: @DougKimzey `FaceGrids` option works for me (MMa 11.3). Maybe the lightning setting `Lighting->{{"Ambient",None}}` is causing you trouble?

Comment: I am also using 11.3.  I removed the Lighting.  and tried  Graphics3D[hexShape, FaceForm[], Axes->True, FaceGrids->All] and  Graphics3D[{{hexShape, FaceForm[], Axes->True, FaceGrids->All}}]  I must be using Graphics3D incorrectly.

Comment: @DougKimzey yes. take a look at graphics3d docs. Options should be outside of `{}`.

Comment: Cometh the dawn...